# HTML : Can't click the save button

Tags: html

Keep changing the code but still can't click the save button.

here the code :

```
<tr>
  <td align="center" valign="middle">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_basic" id="btn_basic" value="Save" disabled="disabled" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is more a HTML question. And a very silly mistake.

Comment: Did you read the code, *at all*?

Comment: the disabled is there because of this function ..

`function validate()
{
  if((\$('txt_pendaftaran').value !='')&&(\$('txt_syarikat').value != '')&&(\$('txt_alamat').value != '')&&(\$('txt_sumber').value != '')&&(\$('txt_dtiklan').value != '')&&(\$('txt_jawatan').value != '')){
      \$('btn_simpan').disabled = false;
  }
  else{
      \$('btn_simpan').disabled = true;
  }
}`

Comment: @Zeko Great! Remove it.

Comment: remove disabled="disabled"

Answer (score 7):

You have `disabled="disabled"` in it. This means it's disabled. Disabled means you won't be able to press the button.

Answer (score 5):

Remove `disabled="disabled"` from the `input` tag. The `disabled` attribute disables any field.